# How would I select this with CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Lets say I have the following..

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div></div>  <<<Select this one..
            <div></div>  <<<Not this one..
            <div></div>  <<<Select this one..
            <div></div>  <<<Select this one..
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How would I select those 3 `divs` without adding any classes or ids? Is this even possible?

Comment: `:not(:nth-child(2))` should do it, but not in older versions of IE.

Comment: css3 selectors can do this in pure CSS but if you want a safe backwards compatible solution you should use either javascript or classes to accomplish this

Comment: @Dalton Dingus: Firstly your example code looks a lot like "Divitis". So it is semantically very "bad code". **How would I select those 3 divs without adding any classes or ids?** The "problem" with the accepted answer is, that it will match **everywhere** where you have such a structure of nested DIVs. This is normally not wanted and that's exactly what IDs and Classes are for. Additionally tag selectors should be avoided. So both, the HTML markup and the CSS code are an example for "bad practice".

Comment: You can also use <span>s inside the <div>s. No pseudo selectors needed for the <div> tags. Inline style your <span>s

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [:not()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) and [:nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) pseudo-classes.

```css
div > div > div > div:not(:nth-child(2)){
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>Test</div> 
      <div>Test</div>
      <div>Test</div>
      <div>Test</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### [Demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/QwU7x/)

> **Note**: For [ie8 support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3), you could use the same selector in jQuery and style your element that way.
>
> ```js
> $("div > div > div > div:not(:nth-child(2))")
>  .css("background-color", "yellow")
> ```
>
> ```html
> <div>
>   <div>
>     <div>
>       <div>Test</div> 
>       <div>Test</div>
>       <div>Test</div>
>       <div>Test</div>
>     </div>
>   </div>
> </div>
>
> <!-- External Resources -->
> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
> ```

Comment: An alternative could be `div:not(:only-child):not(:nth-child(2))` with the same compatibility but less div. Just another example of a useful CSS3 selector

Comment: @KyleMit AWESOME! Thanks for the excellent answer and the jQuery! So helpful - you are the best answer

Comment: @FelipeAls, that is some pretty cool *css*.  I'd worry that it would be more likely to break, but without knowing what changes would be made to this example, it could be the case that mine breaks just as easily.

Comment: Hey, tiny thing, but you forgot the close paren for the `:not` in the jQuery. Here is a link to a fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/QwU7x/

Comment: @MirroredFate, thanks!  big thing!  That's the original link to the fiddle, so I think you just ran it, instead of updating or forking, but I closed the paren in the post and updated the fiddle.  Thanks

Comment: @KyleMit: I am not the downvoter, but ... just because things are doable that does not mean one should do. At least answers should state the problems and drawbacks (also see my comment to question above). Otherwise the questioner won't learn anything and might be of the mistaken assumption that he is doing it all in the right way. Personally I'm very surprised about 10 upvotes for such a "selector construction" ... :-( And Javascript as fallback for CSS seems to me a bit "counterproductive".

Comment: @Netsurfer: Yeah but it's not really the answerer's fault that the markup given in the question is set up that way, is it?

Comment: @BoltClock: Of course it is not. So the only thing I complained about was, that it was not mentioned with a single sentence in any of the answers! This is by the way one thing I dislike about Stackoverflow. People just try to answer the question no matter how senseless the concern is. And do not even point this out to the questioner.

Comment: @Netsurfer, good points all around.  Sometimes I think of SO questions as little brain teasers and forget to add some sanity checking.  Definitely, if possible, styling with classes is a better way to go.  If, however, for some reason you didn't have control over the HTML being delivered, but were writing an extension that could add js or css, you'd have to do something like this.  +1 for your answer as well.  Lot's of ways to skin a cat.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to support IE7 you can use:

```
div > div > div > div + div + div, 
div > div > div > div:first-child {
    color: orange;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4TYcb/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
div div div :not(:nth-child(2))
```

will select just those divs

Comment: This will also select any element that happens to be a child of the third div, even if it's not a div.  There aren't any in this example, but there likely could be.

Comment: In fact, any element that's not the second child that happens to be somewhere within the third `div`, if that third `div` has an entire complex hierarchy going on.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a solution that also works for older IEs you have to think a bit different than supposed by most of the answers so far.

Style all DIVs that are the third child:

```
div > div > div > div {/* styles for all 4 DIVs */}
```

And then change the second one back:

```
div > div > div > div:first-child + div {/* styles only for the second DIV */}
```

See [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8tQXW/)

But as already written in my comment on your question, your HTML markup is highly "questionable".

PS: The difference to @Adrift's answer is, that the second rule selects the second DIV. IMHO this is more useful in practice rather than to exclude an element. It is also "more robust" just in case another element than a DIV will be inserted.

As you just wrote that this is not what you are looking for, here is another option to achieve "**what you are looking for**"!

In your case you could also use the `:nth-of-type()` selector, instead of the `:nth-child()` one - see [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mLM5G/1/)

As you see there is a whole bunch of options. You should take the time and try to understand all these different approaches to be able to decide which one will fit your needs best!

Comment: Not what I was looking for.

Comment: You are kidding, aren't you? Have you had a look at the Fiddle!? Beside the other options that were already given in the other answers, this is one even supported by older IEs and more flexible in case you have to change your markup one day. But without knowing more details about your site it is not possible to decide which option might be best.